# How to update soap xml file element value in c#.net

Tags: c#, xml, soap

How can I update the SOAP xml element value from an soap xml file using c#.net? My file is as below:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Header>
      <Action  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://extn.ssac.ee.sim.dsh.cms.hhs.gov/SsaCompositePortType/VerifySSAResponse</Action>
      <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:27f0af81-0da7-441f-83a7-fb2beaf30664</MessageID>
      <RelatesTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">uuid:e8dcd685-cb86-400a-8059-dcad985a7ea7</RelatesTo>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <exch:SSACompositeResponse xmlns:exch="http://ssac.ee.sim.dsh.cms.hhs.gov">
         <ssac:SSACompositeIndividualResponse xmlns:ssac="http://extn.ssac.ee.sim.dsh.cms.hhs.gov">
            <ssac:ResponseMetadata>
               <ssac:ResponseCode>HS000000</ssac:ResponseCode>
              <ssac:ResponseDescriptionText>Success</ssac:ResponseDescriptionText>
            </ssac:ResponseMetadata>
          <ssac:PersonSSNIdentification>199123051</ssac:PersonSSNIdentification>
        <ssac:SSAResponse>
           <ssac:SSNVerificationIndicator>true</ssac:SSNVerificationIndicator>
           <ssac:DeathConfirmationCode>Unconfirmed</ssac:DeathConfirmationCode>
           <nc:PersonUSCitizenIndicator xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0">true</nc:PersonUSCitizenIndicator>
           <ssac:PersonIncarcerationInformationIndicator>false</ssac:PersonIncarcerationInformationIndicator>
           <ssac:SSATitleIIAnnualIncomeInformationIndicator>false</ssac:SSATitleIIAnnualIncomeInformationIndicator>
           <ssac:SSATitleIIMonthlyIncomeInformationIndicator>false</ssac:SSATitleIIMonthlyIncomeInformationIndicator>
           <ssac:SSAQuartersOfCoverageInformationIndicator>false</ssac:SSAQuartersOfCoverageInformationIndicator>
        </ssac:SSAResponse>
     </ssac:SSACompositeIndividualResponse>
  </exch:SSACompositeResponse>
```

Here I want to update ssac:PersonSSNIdentification (199123051) value to 9876543210?

```
                XmlNamespaceManager xnm;
                xnm = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
                xnm.AddNamespace("soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
                var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(newSSAPathName);
                XmlNodeList aNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Envelope/Body/SSACompositeResponse/SSACompositeIndividualResponse");
                foreach (XmlNode aNode in aNodes)
                {  var innerXmlNode = aNode.SelectSingleNode("/PersonSSNIdentification");
                    if (innerXmlNode != null)
                    {  innerXmlNode.Value = lstSsn[0];
                    }
                }
                xmlDoc.Save(newSSAPathName);
```

But this doesn't work...is there any way...

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: well I tried this using XmlNamespaceManager and XmlDocument..but not working

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing this with [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) rather than the older `XmlDocument` API.

First, load your XML into an [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
        var doc = XDocument.Load(newSSAPathName);
```

Then, define an [`XNamespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for each of the namespaces you have in your XML:

```
        var soap = (XNamespace)"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";
        var exch = (XNamespace)"http://ssac.ee.sim.dsh.cms.hhs.gov";
        var ssac = (XNamespace)"http://extn.ssac.ee.sim.dsh.cms.hhs.gov";
```

Now query for all [elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at the required depth in the XML hierarchy with the required fully qualified names:

```
        var ssnIds = doc.Elements(soap + "Envelope")
            .Elements(soap + "Body")
            .Elements(exch + "SSACompositeResponse")
            .Elements(ssac + "SSACompositeIndividualResponse")
            .Elements(ssac + "PersonSSNIdentification");
```

Finally, change the appropriate element value:

```
        foreach (var ssnId in ssnIds)
            if (ssnId.Value == "199123051")
                ssnId.Value = "9876543210";
```

Alternatively, if you do want to use an XPATH query, you need to populate an [`XmlNamespaceManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with all 3 namespaces. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356942%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `XPathSelectElements(XNode, String, IXmlNamespaceResolver)` shows how to do this. Then use the prefixes you chose corresponding to each namespace in your XPATH query:

```
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(newSSAPathName))
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

            // Set up a namespaceManager as described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351355%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
            var nameTable = reader.NameTable;
            var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
            namespaceManager.AddNamespace("soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
            namespaceManager.AddNamespace("exch", "http://ssac.ee.sim.dsh.cms.hhs.gov");
            namespaceManager.AddNamespace("ssac", "http://extn.ssac.ee.sim.dsh.cms.hhs.gov");

            var ssnIds = doc.XPathSelectElements("soap:Envelope/soap:Body/exch:SSACompositeResponse/ssac:SSACompositeIndividualResponse/ssac:PersonSSNIdentification", namespaceManager);

            foreach (var ssnId in ssnIds)
                if (ssnId.Value == "199123051")
                    ssnId.Value = "9876543210";
        }
```

Be sure to do `using System.Xml.XPath;` at the beginning of the file since `XPathSelectElements` is an extension method.

**Update**

Using `XmlDocument`, the equivalent XPATH query is:

```
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(newSSAPathName);

        var nameTable = xmlDoc.NameTable;
        var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
        namespaceManager.AddNamespace("soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
        namespaceManager.AddNamespace("exch", "http://ssac.ee.sim.dsh.cms.hhs.gov");
        namespaceManager.AddNamespace("ssac", "http://extn.ssac.ee.sim.dsh.cms.hhs.gov");

        var ssnIds = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("soap:Envelope/soap:Body/exch:SSACompositeResponse/ssac:SSACompositeIndividualResponse/ssac:PersonSSNIdentification", namespaceManager);

        foreach (XmlNode ssnId in ssnIds)
            if (ssnId.InnerText == "199123051")
                ssnId.InnerText = "9876543210";
```